# Nested foreach loop displaying duplicate results php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested

I have function that is supposed to match arrays together using the `array_intersect` function. I'm trying to match a product name with possible offers with same name from multiple merchants. My issue now is I'm using nested `foreach` loops and whenever I run it, the loop is always infinite and it prints duplicate results.

Here's the function:

```
function get_matching_product3(&$catalogue, $stock) {

    $stockSmallCase = array_map('strtolower', $stock);
    $catalogueSmallCase = array_map('strtolower', $catalogue);

foreach ($catalogueSmallCase as $key => $value)
{
   $catalogueKey = $key;
   $catalogueValue = $value;
   $catalogueTokens = explode (' ', $catalogueValue);

    foreach ($stockSmallCase as $key => $value) {
        $stockKey = $key;
        $stockValue = $value;
        $stockTokens = explode (' ', $stockValue);

        $match= array_intersect($stockTokens, $catalogueTokens);
        $m = count($match);    
        $t = count($catalogueTokens);  

            //echo $m;
            //echo $t;

        if (($m > 1) && (($m / $t) * 100) >= 90) {        
            //print_r($match);
            echo = $catalogueKey." ".$stockKey;
            //echo "</br>";
            //echo $stockKey;


        }       
    }
}

  return null;
}
```

Comment: If you want some help, you need to post the two arrays (with false values obviously). Otherwise it is too difficult to see how they look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
foreach ($catalogueSmallCase as $key => $value)
```

and

```
foreach ($stockSmallCase as $key => $value)
```

I think the problem came from the $key and $value variables. They are probably misunderstood by php at some time of the loop.

Try changing it in order to différenciates it.